# link_to syntax with rails3 (link_to_remote) and basic javascript not working in a rails3 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

i am wondering if the basic link_to syntax is completely broken in current rails3 master or if i am doing some wrong syntax here.

```
= link_to "name", nil, :onlick => "alert('Hello world!');"
```

should actually produce an alert on click. very simple. does not work on my rails3 project! (also no error output!) any ideas?

for the general link_to syntax i could not find an example where i could combine a link_to_remote with a confirmation, remote and html class (see my try below)

```
= link_to "delete", {:action => "destroy", :remote => true, :method => :delete, :confirm => "#{a.title} wirklich L&ouml;schen?" }, :class => "trash"
```

even the rails3 api does not help me here: http://rails3api.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok it looks like the new unobtrusive javascript changes introduced the problem.
see the following post for more information if you run into similar issues
http://blog.loopedstrange.com/modest-rubyist-archive/rails-3-ujs-and-csrf-meta-tags

```
 <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

fixed things for me.

Comment: thanks, simianarmy - i just updated the link to a working version of the archived content.

Answer (score 13):

I believe your problem here is that you've set the link up to show the alert when it is licked, as opposed to when it is clicked. ;)

As for `link_to_remote`, it has changed with the switch to unobtrusive javascript. You can read about it here: http://blog.solnic.eu/2009/09/08/unobtrusive-javascript-helpers-in-rails-3.html

Comment: hehe, thanks for the tip with the typo. unfortunately, that was not the problem but the new unobtrusive javascript helpers need a meta tag include. thanks for the pointer though! ;)

Answer (score 3):

nil doesn't work:

```
= link_to "name", nil, :onclick => "alert('Hello world!');"
=> <a href="/currentpath", onclick="alert('Hello world!');">name</a>
```

You should use:

```
= link_to "name", "#", :onclick => "alert('Hello world!');"
=> <a href="#", onclick="alert('Hello world!');">name</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other answers here work for you then maybe this will help.

So the csrf_meta_tag declaration was not enough for me, though should be added in your layout file for Rails 3 anyway. With me it turned out to be a conflict with jQuery. I just put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

after the rails scripts tag in my layout and the clash between Prototype and jQuery was resolved. Hey presto I was getting the confirmation dialog box on delete.

This technique also resolved my original issue when using link_to to try and delete a record. With link_to any destroy command seemed to redirecting to the show page for the record. Hence I moved to button_to based on some other solution I saw, but with no confirmation. I wonder if there are some more deep seated issues with jQuery and Prototype.

This all happened on an upgraded Rails 2.3.5 app that seemed to be working okay without needing to include Prototype or :defaults in my layout file.

On a side note I did follow these instructions:

http://webtech.union.rpi.edu/blog/2010/02/21/jquery-and-rails-3/

to try and lose Prototype all together for this project and use the jQuery git submodule for Rails 3 instead. Following these instructions did not work and I was still without confirm dialogs with button_to and the show page when using link_to. Just thought I'd mention it so save someone the trouble of trying this.

Comment: By the way I found the solution from this page:

http://featurenotbug.com/2009/05/getting-jquery-and-prototype-to-work-together-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

An off-topic comment for an answer above since I can't comment yet  :(

@robeastham:
I figured I'd leave some comments that may help with some of the issues you've encoutered.

I've been having the "destroy link re-directing to the show page instead of the index page" issue as well since switching from ActiveRecord to Mongoid, and haven't found a real solution (already have prototype removed).  However, a workaround that works cleanly is to explicitely specify the re-direct path using :location to respond_with:

```
respond_with @themodel, :location => themodels_url
```

As for getting a confirmation pop-up with a button, you could do:

```
button_to "Button Name", { :controller => "your/controller", :action => :action_name, :confirm => "Text for the pop-up"}, { :method => :<method name> }
```

e.g.

```
button_to "Click Here", { :controller => "home", :action -> :set_completed, :confirm => "Mark the item complete?" }, { :method => :put }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`<%= link_to "Recommend", recommend_user_path(@user), :remote => true %>`

Check that this is in your views\layout\application.html.erb (or equivalent):

`<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

Note that Rails v3.2.2 uses "tags" not "tag"