# Rails 3 ajax hyperlink bindings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, prototype

I'm using Rails 3 with default javascript library (prototype, I believe)
and I want to render a link that makes an AJAX call when pressed.

Here's my sample HAML code:

```
= link_to "test link", {controller: :information, action: :faq}, remote: true, id: "abc"
:javascript
  $("abc").bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(){
  alert('begin!');
  })
```

Right now, I'm just testing the code by hand.  The idea is that I should click on the link and an alert box should pop up that says **"begin!"**
but no alert dialog pops up when I click on the hyperlink.

I've also tried to switch the binding from `ajax:beforeSend` to `ajax:before`, but this doesn't work either.

any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458841/link-to-syntax-with-rails3-link-to-remote-and-basic-javascript-not-working-in-a  . It looks like a similar issue.

Comment: augusto, no...i don't think it's the same issue.  I have the csrf_meta_tag, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

$("#abc").bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(){

You are missing the # for the id

Comment: if you use chrome or firebug w/ firefox you can check out the console and it will debug all your javascript troubles. (right click > inspect element > console)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. where did you put the callback code? My first try was to put it in the same link page, but nothing happend. So I move the callback to the application.js, and now it's working.