# Rails 3 link_to partial structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I want to create a `link_to` render `:partial`. I have two partials stored already in the view folder in which I call the `link_to` (which is the profiles views). Getting the JavaScript to load the data is the next step but I am having trouble structuring the `link_to` properly.

Here's what I had:

```
<ul id="infoContainer">
  <li><%= link_to render(:partial => "about") do %>About<% end %></li>
  <li><%= link_to render(:partial => "other") do %>Other<% end %></li>
</ul>
```

Using these, both partials rendered in my `show.html.erb` and the links disappeared.

So I tried the following:

```
<ul id="infoContainer">
  <li><%= link_to render(:partial => 'about'), :class => "a", :remote => true do %>About<% end %></li>
  <li><%= link_to render(:partial => 'other'), :class => "o", :remote => true do %>Other<% end %></li>
</ul>
```

Both partials still show and the "About"/"Other" text links still don't show.

**UPDATE:** So I may have the link_to working. It's just not rendering anything. Gotta fix that with JavaScript I assume.

```
<li><%= link_to "About", (:partial => 'about'}, {:class => "a"}, :remote => true %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Other", (:partial => 'other'}, {:class => "o"}, :remote => true %></li>
```

Using the `link_to` above makes the URL: `/profiles/1?partial=about`

Comment: When using the block form of `link_to` as you are, the first argument is expected to be a URL or an ActiveRecord object, or an options hash. However, you're passing it the result of `render`, which returns a rendered view. Do you want the view returned by that `render` to be the body of that link?

Comment: No, I want the body of the link to just be the word for the link. Then when you click it the view should be the partial.

Comment: Just updated my question. That seems to be working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're using link_to incorrectly -- please check the API / docs

it's called either:

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
  # url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
  # posts_path

link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
  # url_options, except :confirm or :method,
  # is passed to url_for

link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end

link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

See:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

and perhaps:

[link_to syntax with rails3 (link_to_remote) and basic javascript not working in a rails3 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458841/link-to-syntax-with-rails3-link-to-remote-and-basic-javascript-not-working-in)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="infoContainer">
  <li><%= link_to render(:partial => 'about'), urlyouwant %></li>
  <li><%= link_to render(:partial => 'other'), urlyouwant %></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to run javascript when user click on, you can read more at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-link_to_function

```
<ul id="infoContainer">
  <li><%= link_to_function render(:partial => 'about'), "alert('About!')" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to_function render(:partial => 'other'), "alert('Other!')" %></li>
</ul>
```